# Bootstrap Different Padding on Sides

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, padding

**Hello everyone, I'm creating a React App which needs much work on GUI. In I have a div class like:**

```
<div className="col  align-middle p-2"> Something </div>
```

**I know that bootstrap provides both side paddings on X and Y alignment. How there a chance to give different bootstrap paddings on each side ? Like left side  10 unit padding, top side 15 unit padding etc**

Answer (score 1):

you might want to write your own CSS rules for a class that will consistently require `padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 5px;`